# How to build, sort and print a tree of a sort?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, xhtml

This is more of an algorithmic dilemma than a language-specific problem, but since I'm currently using Ruby I'll tag this as such. I've already spent over 20 hours on this and I would've never believed it if someone told me writing a LaTeX parser was a walk in the park in comparison.

I have a loop to read hierarchies (that are prefixed with \m) from different files

```
art.tex: \m{Art}
graphical.tex: \m{Art}{Graphical}
me.tex: \m{About}{Me}
music.tex: \m{Art}{Music}
notes.tex: \m{Art}{Music}{Sheet Music}
site.tex: \m{About}{Site}
something.tex: \m{Something}
whatever.tex: \m{Something}{That}{Does Not}{Matter}
```

and I need to sort them alphabetically and print them out as a tree

```
About
    Me (me.tex)
    Site (site.tex)
Art (art.tex)
    Graphical (graphical.tex)
    Music (music.tex)
        Sheet Music (notes.tex)
Something (something.tex)
    That
        Does Not
            Matter (whatever.tex)
```

in (X)HTML

```
<ul>
<li>About</li>
<ul>
<li><a href="me.tex">Me</a></li>
<li><a href="site.tex">Site</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="art.tex">Art</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="graphical.tex">Graphical</a></li>
<li><a href="music.tex">Music</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="notes.tex">Sheet Music</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
<li><a href="something.tex">Something</a></li>
<ul>
<li>That</li>
<ul>
<li>Doesn't</li>
<ul>
<li><a href="whatever.tex">Matter</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
```

using Ruby without Rails, which means that at least Array.sort and Dir.glob are available.

All of my attempts were formed like this (as this part should work just fine).

```
def fss_brace_array(ss_input)#a concise version of another function; converts {1}{2}...{n} into an array [1, 2, ..., n] or returns an empty array
    ss_output = ss_input[1].scan(%r{\{(.*?)\}})
rescue
    ss_output = []
ensure
    return ss_output
end
#define tree
s_handle = File.join(:content.to_s, "*")
Dir.glob("#{s_handle}.tex").each do |s_handle|
    File.open(s_handle, "r") do |f_handle|
        while s_line = f_handle.gets
            if s_all = s_line.match(%r{\\m\{(\{.*?\})+\}})
                s_all = s_all.to_a
                #do something with tree, fss_brace_array(s_all) and s_handle
                break
            end
        end
    end
end
#do something else with tree
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution in Python after simply pushing all of the entries into an array.

```
import operator
import itertools
def overput(input):
    for betweenput, output in itertools.groupby(input, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
        yield '<li>'
        yield betweenput
        output = [x[1:] for x in output if len(x) > 1]
        if output:
            yield '<ul>'
            for part in overput(output):
                yield part
            yield '</ul>'
        yield '</li>'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Important:** I can't SSH into my linux box from work right now, which means I cannot test this code. Not even the tiniest bit. It could have silly, obvious syntax errors or logic since I wrote it from scratch right in the input box. But it LOOKS right... I think. I'll check it when I get home from work.

```
SOURCE = <<-INPUT
  art.tex: \m{Art}
  graphical.tex: \m{Art}{Graphical}
  me.tex: \m{About}{Me}
  music.tex: \m{Art}{Music}
  notes.tex: \m{Art}{Music}{Sheet Music}
  site.tex: \m{About}{Site}
  something.tex: \m{Something}
  whatever.tex: \m{Something}{That}{Does Not}{Matter}
INPUT
HREF = '#href'

def insert_leaves(tree,node_list)
  next = node_list[0]
  rest = node_list[1..-1]
  tree[next] ||= {}
  if not rest.empty?
    insert_leaves(tree[next],rest)
  else
    tree[next]
    # recursively, this will fall out to be the final result, making the
    # function return the last (deepest) node inserted.
  end
end

tree = {}

SOURCE.each_line do |line|
  href, folder_string = line.split(': \\m') #=> ['art.tex','{Art}{Graphical}']
  folders = folder_string.scan(/[^{}]+/)     #=> ['Art','Graphical']
  deepest_folder = insert_leaves(tree,folders)
  deepest_folder[HREF] = href
end

# After this insertion, tree looks like this:
#
# {
#   About = {
#     Me = {
#       #href = me.tex
#     }
#     Site = {
#       #href = site.tex
#     }
#   }
#   Art = {
#     Graphical = {
#       #href = graphical.tex
#     }
#     ...
#
# Edge case: No category should be named '#href'.

def recursive_html_construction(branch, html)
  return if branch.keys.reject(HREF).empty? # abort if the only key is
                                            # an href.
  html << '<ul>'
  branch.keys.sort.each do |category|
    next if category == HREF # skip href entries.
    html << '<li>'
    if branch[category].key?(HREF)
      html << "<a href='#{branch[category][HREF]}'> #{category}</a>"
    else
      html << category
    end
    html << '</li>'
    recursive_html_construction(branch[category],html)
  end
  html << '</ul>'
end

html = ""

recursive_html_construction(tree,html)

puts html # => '<ul><li>About</li><ul><li><a href='me.tex'>Me</a></li><li>
          #     <a href='site.tex'>Site</a></li></ul><li>Art</li><ul><li>
          #     <a href='graphical.tex'>Graphical</a></li>...
```

Comment: +1 that looks like it should work, which I don't think I could do without irb

Comment: @Jim I did cheat on looking up a few functions online. Of course, I never got around to testing it... forgot when I got home. :-) And of course I'm at work again...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Ruby, but this is how could you do it in most languages:

1. Make an empty tree structure.
2. For each line:
3. For each {} element after \m:
4. If this element can be found in a tree at the same level, do nothing.
5. Otherwise create a tree node that is a child of the previous element or a root if it is the first one
6. At the end of the line, attach the foo.tex part the the leafmost node.

I do not know how this translates to Ruby, specifically, how tree structure is represented there.

Comment: Trees can be represented as hashes in hashes in Ruby: tree = {"a" => {"b" => {"c" => nil, "d" => nil}}, "e" => {"f"}}. The only problem is that Array.sort will convert this to an array and also take the file paths into account.

Answer (score 0):

There was a question very similar to this one recently, take a look at mine and other answers:

[How to handle recursive parent/child problems like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403006/how-to-handle-recursive-parent-child-problems-like-this/2403291#2403291)